# Can't transfer files using FTP script and batch on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a folder with PDF files locally on hard disk and I want to upload files from this folder to an FTP server.

So I created a batch file that should upload PDF files to the FTP server. Everything seems to work fine and the console window displays `File successfully transferred`, but actually no file really uploaded.

The FTP script content:

```
open
000.000.000.000  -- not the real ftp server ip lol 
bla@nirlatpro.com
PASSWORD
mput c:\Batch\*.pdf
quit
```

Command window with output on running this script:

[image: Lines output in console window on running the script]

It looks like it works, but no file is actually uploaded.

What is even more strange is if I connect to FTP using GUI application and drag the files, it does work and all the files are uploaded to the server.

summary:
- It's works fine if i'm using windows explore and dragg the files.
- It's not uploading the files if i'm using cmd commands or batch script with ftp file, even if the console window displays `'File successfully transferred'`

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the above .bat where you do a 'cd' to set the destination directory on the server.   I'm betting the files are on the server just not in the directory where you are expecting them to be.

Comment: Did you try executing all the commands by running them manually from the cmd prompt.

Comment: I tried manually from the cmd, it's still not uploading the files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a permissions problem 
apparently the ftp server does not allowing to copy files in to the root directory /

[console window display it "Current restricted directory is / "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHdMm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I too Faced a similar problem downloading a file from ftp through command line, But every time my request was rejected and my connection was not established.
After a thorough research i found the t i need to do settings in the IIS for ftp.

Steps:

1) Set your IIS Server on.
a:Goto control panel-->Programs&Features-->Turn windows Features on or off-->Internet Information Services.
b: Expand the Internet Information services-->Check FTP services-->Expand FTP Server-->FTP Service (Check it)-->press OK.

2)Open IIS Manager(win+r-->inetmgr)
a: Select FTP authentication-->Enable Anonymous Authentication or Base Authentication (as per your requirement).
b: Select FTP Authorization-->Select All users, give permissions (read or write or both) & press ok.
c) Open FTP Directory Browsing select MS-DOS for windows Server or Unix for Unix server.

3) Finally goto Services.msc(win+r-->'services.msc')-->MicrosoftFTPServices-->restart.

Now goto your command prompt and write your respective code for ftp it will work.